# What would happen after the big crunch?

Tags: cosmology, universe

What is the aftermath of the [big crunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch)?

Answer (score 3):

Singularity. If a big crunch occurs, the entire universe will collapse under it's own gravity until everything is concentrated at one point. What happens after that is really up to speculation.

Moreover, in light of recent discoveries, this theory has been dismissed as being a implausible one. There is evidence that the universe is expanding at an accelerated rate due to the presence of something known as dark energy, about which little is currently known except for the fact that it is repulsive and counteracts the effect of gravity, allowing the universe to expand. Attempts at calculations suggest that dark energy increases over time as the universe expands, and this has raised doubts over the current explanations provided by the cosmological model.

Comment: It need not be one point.

Comment: @MBN Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user13068: the answers to [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) explain why the Big Bang didn't happen at a point. The same arguments explain why the Big Crunch doesn't happen at a point.

Comment: So is the rephrase "in the big crunch gravity will cause the spatial distance between all objects in the universe to become 0" correct?

Comment: Stricktly speaking you don't have a matric at the singularity. The singularity is not part of the manifold. So distances make no sense.

Comment: @user13068: the spacing between spacetime points at the Big Crunch is no defined because the metric is singular (or as MBN says, more precisely the Big Crunch isn't part of spacetime). However as we approach the Big Crunch the spacing between any pair of spacetime points tends to zero.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the universe will restart over and over and over and over again and maybe the same events take place like when the last universe was created knowing that we aren't the first humans to be living but then maybe we are the millionth generation of humans to exist but the cycle continues forever until the big freeze happens which when the universe keeps expanding and nothing happens no living organisms just a cold void with nothing and another universe gets created in another real/dimension and the cycle continues on forever.

Comment: Welcome on the Physics SE! Note, this site collects mainly experimentally verifiable facts.